# python multiline group regex

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm trying to extract the mpath name "DS4800_VG_STAGE*" and the number of online paths from the output of multipath -ll.

> DS4800_VG_STAGE_2 (3600a0b80004710ce00001ce24e08ce1c) dm-6 IBM,1815      FAStT
>   [size=241G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=1 rdac][rw]
>   \_ round-robin 0 [prio=100][active]
>    \_ 1:0:1:5 sdc 8:32  [active][ready]
>   \_ round-robin 0 [prio=0][enabled]
>    \_ 2:0:1:5 sdf 8:80  [active][ghost]
>   DS4800_VG_STAGE_1 (3600a0b80004706be00001ece4e08ca4f) dm-8 IBM,1815      FAStT
>   [size=24112G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=1 rdac][rw]
>   \_ round-robin 0 [prio=100][active]
>    \_ 1:0:1:5 sdc 8:32  [active][ready]
>   \_ round-robin 0 [prio=0][enabled]
>    \_ 2:0:1:5 sdf 8:80  [active][ghost]

I've managed to extract the path name but am struggling with collecting the rest of the multiline output into a single group so I can process how many paths are on-line in group2.

```
^(\w+\s+).+?$$((?:[^\\\\]+\n+)+)
```

Match1:
`Group 1 = "DS4800_VG_STAGE_2"`
`Group 2 = "[size=241G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=1 rdac][rw]"`

Match2:
`Group 1 = "DS4800_VG_STAGE_1"`
`Group 2 = "[size=24112G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=1 rdac][rw]"`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific about which lines you're trying to parse out? I'm unfamiliar with this command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
^(\w+\s+).+?$$\n((?:.+?\n+)+)
```

I think in your expression you are using [^\\] which is preventing any line with backslash from being caught in the expression. But every line (following the first two "header lines") starts with a backslash.